# Why background GC suspends user threads?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, profiling, timeline, dottrace

I`m currently profiling my application with dotTrace Timeline. I found that a lot of time is spent in GC, which is expected, but what is not expected is that I see a lot of time user threads are suspended during Background collection.

profiler screenshots :

[image: profiler screenshots]

From image I see that I have two threads doing some CPU bound work, then 'Background' GC occur, and first thread is suspended a bit later and second suspended immediately.

[image: threads blocked]

You can see that user threads indeed are blocked by Garbage collector thread.

I know there could be foreground blocking GC of Gen 0 and Gen 1 during background GC. But this is not a case since all GC is on Gen 2.

I created basic reproduction solution on github:
https://github.com/isaevdan/BackgroundGCSuspendsThreads

Comment: Even concurrent GCs have some "stop the world" phases at the beginning and in the middle of execution. Here, what's suspicious, is pretty long execution time (700 ms is a lot). Maybe dotTrace is incorrectly reporting this? Have you tried to use PerfView and its GCStats report?

Comment: @KonradKokosa yes. I did one more run and collect ETW events with PerfView. Here is screenshot of gc events for this GC. https://prnt.sc/rqyae3

Comment: To give some insight on what is going on in application. I create a Dictionary<decimal, int> of size 10_000_000 and int[] of same size. I do same in two threads. My initial goal was find out what causes difference in time when you create this in one thread(4s) versus you create it in parallel on two threads(5s). Meaning I create 2 arrays and dictionaries of 10_000_000 size. So far my decision is that the problem is in GC. But I don`t get why background GC suspending all threads

Comment: LOH allocations are synchronized between threads, that's probably why you observe such timings. In regards to thread suspension, I would love to see GCStats report from PerfView

Comment: @KonradKokosa I don`t know what is best way to share big files here. So I just put a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CbetcSAqRlHXdCAZty13TnONIVqE7d0G/view?usp=sharing) to my Google Drive. I also never heard of synchronized LOH allocations. Do you have some resources to read more about this? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it, as soon as I will manage to find some free time! Regarding resources you can for sure start from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals or... from my book.

Comment: @KonradKokosa I just read this documenation before posting and posted here because didn't find anything that could explain background collections that blocks user threads. I'm interested in exact part of synchronized LOH allocations, because didn't see that anywhere before. BTW I created basic reproduction repository on github: https://github.com/isaevdan/BackgroundGCSuspendsThreads